# Custom post type or just use custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, database

I am turning a restaurants website into a wordpress website to allow for the customer to take over content changes. The restaurant has a menu that has categories like Baskets with different types. For instance under the Basket type there is Fish which has a Title, Description, and Price. So what I want to do is to be able to have the customer create or delete Menu categories and have the ability to create,delete, update menu types. Then the entire menu is shown on one page. You can view the page at [www.tailfinstogo.com/menu.html](http://www.tailfinstogo.com/menu.html).

Comment: You mean [something like this](http://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20110427-011659.png)?

Comment: Exactly like that! That looks like a bunch of work though. Did you do that with custom taxonomy and post types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can really do it either way. I would personally make a custom post type of "Menu Item" then use a custom taxonomy for type of food (e.g., 'Baskets', 'Poboys', 'Soups', etc.). I would then have a custom fields for sizes and price so you could enter something like '4pc' and '10pc' and '7.99'.

One of things I've learned with doing WP sites for clients is that training for the client is often overlooked. Just because you do a great job designing and developing the site does not mean the client will know how to use it. I would recommend taking the time to train your client how to use the site after you implement whatever solution you decide on.

Good luck!

Comment: Ah, custom taxonomy! Good call! Yeah, I thought about the client training thing, but luckily for me I know their IT guy and he is pretty sharp so training shouldn't be too bad. Thanks for the answer.